# android edittext background image starting of cursor

Tags: android

I had set background image for Edittext. But when the user clicks on edittext the starting point of cursor is appeared before the editext background image and it looks ubnormal. Is there any solution. Thanks in advance.

**EditText cursor starts like the image shown**

[image: EditText cursor starts like the image shown]

[image]

Comment: are u set edittext's background image in xml file or in java file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please used left Padding in Edittext so your problem may be solved.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use 9-patch image.
If you dont know about 9-patch image then please study

[9-Patch link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

android:paddingLeft="5dp"

Comment: Good answer, but it was answered before 2 years.